# Must provide source or customer. laravel 8 stripe payment gateway

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, banking

Must provide source or customer. laravel 8 stripe payment gateway

**StripeController**

```
 public function stripe()
{
    return view('stripe');
}

public function stripePost(Request $request)
{
    Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
    Stripe\Charge::create ([
            "amount" => 100*100,
            "currency" => "INR",
            "source" => $request->stripeToken,
            "description" => "This payment is testing purpose of websolutionstuff.com",
    ]);

    Session::flash('success', 'Payment Successful !');
       
    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**stripe.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h3 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 40px;margin-bottom: 40px;">Stripe Payment</h3>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default credit-card-box">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3>Payment Details</h3>
                        <div>
                            {{-- <img class="img-responsive pull-right" src="http://i76.imgup.net/accepted_c22e0.png"> --}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (Session::has('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                            <p>{{ Session::get('success') }}</p><br>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <br>
                    <form role="form" action="{{ route('stripe.post') }}" method="post" class="require-validation"
                        data-cc-on-file="false" data-stripe-publishable-key="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}"
                        id="payment-form">
                        @csrf
                        <div class='form-row row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 form-group required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Name on Card</label>
                                <input class='form-control' size='4' type='text'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 form-group required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Card Number</label>
                                <input autocomplete='off' class='form-control card-number' size='20' type='text'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='form-row row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group cvc required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>CVC</label>
                                <input autocomplete='off' class='form-control card-cvc' placeholder='ex. 311'
                                    size='4' type='text'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group expiration required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Expiration Month</label>
                                <input class='form-control card-expiry-month' placeholder='MM' size='2' type='text'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group expiration required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Expiration Year</label>
                                <input class='form-control card-expiry-year' placeholder='YYYY' size='4'
                                    type='text'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{-- <div class='form-row row'>
                     <div class='col-md-12 error form-group hide'>
                        <div class='alert-danger alert'>Please correct the errors and try
                           again.
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div> --}}
                        <div class="form-row row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Pay Now</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```